# Generate image using html2canvas not importing images from remote server

Tags: node.js, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas lib to generate png image from html code. The html combine local images (from images folder) and remote images (from url address - server). The image is looking great but the remote images is missing. any idea how can i fix that issue?

```
 $('#save').click(function () {
   var elm = $('.media_container_1200628').get(0);
   var width = "1200";
   var height = "628";
   html2canvas(elm).then(function (canvas) {
   Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, width, height);
  })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation you should allow cross-origin images to taint the canvas.
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

In your specific case you can do the following:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
   var elm = $('.media_container_1200628').get(0);
   var width = "1200";
   var height = "628";
   html2canvas(elm, { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {
   Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, width, height);
  })
});
```